# How to write an Insert Select Statement?

Tags: jdatabase

This  [Method for creating a subquery using JDatabase](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1/method-for-creating-a-subquery-using-jdatabase) provides some great insight and I think it would be beneficial to have a agreed method of subquery documented. I came across this because I am wanting to do the same thing but as an insert statement. The closest I ever got was replicated the entire table because for some reason I keep losing the columns.

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$pre = $db->getQuery(true);

// Insert columns.
$columns = array('user_id', 'title', 'ordering', 'published', 'description');

$now = $query->currentTimestamp();
// Insert values.

$pre->insert($db->qn('#__table'))->columns($db->qn($columns));


// Prepare the insert query.
$query->select(array(
                    $db->q('') . ' AS id',
                    $db->qn('user_id'),
                    $db->qn('c.name', 'title'),
                    $db->q('1') . ' AS published',
                    $db->q('') . ' AS ordering',
                    $db->q('') . ' AS created_by',
                    $now .  ' AS created_on',
                    $db->q('') . ' AS modified_by',
                    $db->q('') . ' AS modified_on',
                    )
            )
            ->from($db->qn('#__other_table', 'c'));

    $query = $pre . $query ;

    // Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
    $db->setQuery($query);

    $db->execute();
```

Comment: Since writing I am using a `$objects = $db->loadObjectList();` `foreach ($objects AS $obj){ $db->insertObject('#__table', $obj); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is an old question, it might be helpful to others. Here is the insert by select query using JDatabase.

Build some select query using `JDatabase`

```
$querySelect = $db->getQuery(true)
  ->select('id, title')
  ->from('sometable');
```

Now your insert query

```
$queryInsert = $db->getQuery(true)
  ->insert('anothertable')
  ->columns($db->qn(array('id','title')))
  ->values($querySelect)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You have to type which values you want to insert

```
$pre->insert($db->qn('#__table'))->columns($db->qn($columns))->values(here values);
```

Comment: That works for insert values but my question is specifically for insert select.

Comment: This is the right answer to the wrong question.