# Button to execute a mysql query

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql

I made a mysql query that will copy 3 columns of data from one table to another:

```
INSERT INTO eio3k_hikers (link_id, link_name, user_id) SELECT link_id, link_name, user_id FROM eio3k_mt_links where eio3k_mt_links.link_id = (3)
```

I made a button which when clicked it should execute the query.
My code looks like this:

```
<html>
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
</html>

<?php 
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}
require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';

// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // My query 
    $querySelect = $db->getQuery(true);
    $querySelect->select('link_id, link_name, user_id');
    $querySelect->from($db->quoteName('#__mt_links'));
    $querySelect->where($db->quoteName('#__mt_links.link_id')." = ".$db->quote(3));

    $queryInsert = $db->getQuery(true);
    $queryInsert->insert($db->quoteName('#__hikers'));
    $queryInsert->columns($db->quoteName(array('link_id, link_name, user_id')));
    $queryInsert->values($querySelect);
    $db->setQuery($queryInsert);
}
```

When I click on the button, the data does not insert. I also tried this in the last line:

```
$db->setQuery($queryInsert)->execute();
```

But then I got error:

> 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

although they are the same columns in both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Lodder is right.  You've got to set the first query and then also execute it. After the line...

`$db->setQuery($querySelect);`   ... also add a ...

```
$db->execute($querySelect);
```

... then continue on as Lodder suggested. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your `select` and `where` clause

- If you want to select multiple columns, you need to define the columns as an array.
- You don't need to insert the table name in the `where` clause.
- In the `select` clause, you don't appear to be defining the results to then insert

Try this updated code:

```
$querySelect = $db->getQuery(true);
$querySelect->select($db->qn(array('link_id', 'link_name', 'user_id')));
$querySelect->from($db->qn('#__mt_links'));
$querySelect->where($db->qn('link_id') . ' = ' . $db->q(3));
$db->setQuery($querySelect);

$results = $db->loadRowList();
```

`$results` is now the variable that contains your results. It may contain more than 1 row of results so you will then need to use a `foreach` loop when inserting the data.

Have a look through the documentation on how to perform database queries: https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 0):

You ARE NOT going crazy.  MySQL and Joomla DO allow you to `INSERT` rows from a `SELECT` query in a single transaction.  I have tested the following to be successful on my localhost, but if you don't believe me, see [what Nagarjun has to say](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/21790/12352).  Making two separate database calls to `SELECT` then `INSERT` is missing out on a beautiful feature of MySQL.

Here is your lone syntax hiccup:

> ```
> $queryInsert->columns($db->quoteName(array('link_id, link_name, user_id')));
> ```

This says you want to push the 3 columns of data into a single, 27-character column called:

> **`link_id, link_name, user_id`**

Why is that?  You merely missed the inner single quotes and produced a 1-element array.  This would have been an easy thing to overlook, since you probably copy-pasted from your `SELECT` clause.  It should be written like this:

```
$queryInsert->columns($db->quoteName(array('link_id', 'link_name', 'user_id')));
```

I'll suggest some other modifications infused with my personal preferences:

- You can chain your query methods from the `getQuery()` method and spare retyping `$queryWord` on each line.
- Your `select()` method doesn't *need* to receive an array of columns (of course, it *can*).  In your case, a comma separated string containing the three column names is perfectly valid/correct.
- `qn()` (`quoteName()` as you are using it) is not actually necessary for any of the tables or columns that you have mentioned because they are whole words and not "reserved words".
- When you want to secure a dynamic integer value in your query, you can just write `(int)` before it to cast it as an integer.  If you are using static/hardcoded numbers, you can write them without quotes.  If you are using static/hardcoded strings, you can manually wrap them in single quotes.
- In your project, if you are using any user-supplied variables/data as values in your `WHERE` clause, then you should call `q()` (or `quote()`) on your variables for security reasons.
- When your code is live/public, never display your rendered query string or the exact error message.
- A `try {} catch {}` block is a clean way to handle errors that may occur while querying.

My suggested code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
    try {
        $querySelect = $db->getQuery(true)
                          ->select('link_id, link_name, user_id')
                          ->from('#__mt_links')
                          ->where('link_id = 3');

        $queryInsert = $db->getQuery(true)
                          ->insert('#__hikers')
                          ->columns(array('link_id', 'link_name', 'user_id'))
                          ->values($querySelect);

        echo $queryInsert->dump();
        $db->setQuery($queryInsert);
        $db->execute();
        echo "<div>Affected Rows: {$db->getAffectedRows()}</div>";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<div>Error: {$e->getMessage()}</div>";
    }
```

Rendered query (from `->dump()`):

> ```
> INSERT INTO eio3k_hikers
> (link_id,link_name,user_id)
> (
> SELECT link_id, link_name, user_id
> FROM eio3k_mt_links
> WHERE link_id = 3)
> ```