# JDatabase subQuery not work

Tags: jdatabase

I have products table and brads table, i want show record from brands table whit product count.

The query:

```
SELECT a.*, 
    (
       SELECT  COUNT(*)
       FROM    jos_products AS p
       WHERE   p.brand_id = a.id
    ) AS n
     FROM jos_brands AS a 
ORDER BY a.name ASC
```

Resoult on MySQLManager is correct.

```
protected function getListQuery()
{
    $db    = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select          ('a.*');

            $query->subQuery();
                $query->select  ('COUNT(*)');
                $query->from    ('#__products AS p');
                $query->where   ('p.brand_id = a.id');
                $query->as      ('n');
            $query->endSubQuery();

        $query->from            ('#__brands AS a');
        $query->oderby          ('a.name ASC');

    return $query;
}
```

The error is "Undefined property: stdClass::$n" when i try to show the results.

I try this:

```
  protected function getListQuery()
    {
        $db    = JFactory::getDbo();

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query->select          ('a.*');

                $query->subQuery();
                    $query->select  ('COUNT(*) AS n');
                    $query->from    ('#__products AS p');
                    $query->where   ('p.brand_id = a.id');
                $query->endSubQuery();

            $query->from            ('#__brands AS a');
            $query->oderby          ('a.name ASC');

        return $query;
    }
```

But result not is correct.

How to implement my query?

Comment: Please note the spelling mistake in `oderby` too. It should actually be `$query->order()`

Comment: That does not look like Joomla API to me because I've never heard of a subQuery function. Where did you find that information how to build subqueries like this?

Answer (score 1):

Besides that this does not look like Joomla API (see my comment under your question) I don't think that you need a subquery here. Just something like this should work:

```
$query->select('a.*, COUNT(p.*) AS n');
    ->from('#__brands AS a, #__products AS p');
    ->where('p.brand_id = a.id');
    ->order('a.name ASC');
```

Otherwise see here how to implement sub queries in Joomla:
[Method for creating a subquery using JDatabase](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1/method-for-creating-a-subquery-using-jdatabase)