# Translate query from PHP to Jdatabase

Tags: joomla-3.x, jdatabase

This query:

````
SELECT 
rank() over (ORDER BY max(fs_score) desc) AS nr, 
nome_e_cognome AS "Player Name", max(fs_score) AS "Best score" 
FROM scheda_atleta 
INNER JOIN at on at.id=scheda_atleta.atleta 
Group BY at.id, nome_e_cognome;```

produces:
<pre>
+----+----------------+------------+
| nr | Player Name    | Best score|
+----+----------------+------------+
|  1 | Jerry          |      14.32 |
|  2 | Tom Tom        |      11.25 |
+----+----------------+------------+</pre>
````

Comment: welcome to JSE. Have you tried anything yourself thus far? You can read more about `select` queries in Joomla here: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: Yes, I tried. You can see here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28401/selecting-data-from-two-tables-and-make-a-ranking-in-an-html-table

Comment: Could you please update your previous question with any additional information you have, rather than creating a new question.

Comment: Yes, it's my question!

Comment: Plese, I need help for this question: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28401/selecting-data-from-two-tables-and-make-a-ranking-in-an-html-table